# How do I install Tk 8.5?

Tags: package-management

Where can I find the Tk packages?

```
$ sudo apt-get install tk8.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package tk8.5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tk8.5' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: As [snow says](http://askubuntu.com/a/239155/22949), try `sudo apt-get update` before installing (especially if you're installing from the terminal). If that doesn't help, then please *edit your question* to include information about what version of Ubuntu you're running. Please also include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` (you can use the `<$>` tool in the Ask Ubuntu editing toolbar so it's formatted correctly and doesn't take up more space than necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason my apt sources where almost empty.
Adding all available sources through the settings of "Ubuntu Software Center" fixed the issue.

Thank you all for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

these are the results I have produced with the help of `apt-cache search tk8.5`

```
frank@august:~$ apt-cache search tk8.5
tk8.5 - Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11, v8.5 - run-time files
tk8.5-dev - Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11, v8.5 - development files
tk8.5-doc - Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11, v8.5 - manual pages
```

you worth a try with `sudo apt-get update` and then retry with installation.

else you can choose the package from your results of `apt-cache search` , as i have mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get install Tk8.5
```

Tk has a capital "T" in front.  That worked for me.

Comment: packages are not case sensitive.

Comment: It works because `apt-get` is case-insensitive. However all packages in the Ubuntu and Debian archives are lower case.